# Is there a way to add classpath/directories for dependencies on Gradle?

Tags: gradle

I have a new project, it depends on classes at legacy project, not jar files but actual classes.
How can I make these directories a dependency for gradle compile?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35545405/7926064 has some hints and links to bugs and discussions

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
dependencies {
    compile files("relative/path/to/classes/dir")
}
```

For further details, check out the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Comment: This seems add all files in that directory into the classpath as jar files. Can we just add a folder?  I have the same problem.

Comment: This adds the specified directory to the class path, which effectively adds all class files (not Jar files) contained in that directory. This is what the OP asked.

Comment: You are correct. This adds the directory instead of the file of the directory. `fileTree()` add all the files of the folders (recursively) I think.  I am confused with it.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `classpath` instead of `compile` ?

Comment: @elias OP asked "dependency for gradle `compile`"

Comment: `classpath` is only used for buildscript dependencies.  Also, `compile` is now deprecated in favor of `api|implementation`.