# How to include the resources directory, NOT the individual files, into the compile classpath?

Tags: java, netbeans, gradle, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to make [this project](https://github.com/daimor/NBStudio) compile with gradle (version 2.3) instead of ant.

There are two submodules; `cachedb` compiles without problems; as to the other, `NBStudioCore`, I made the full exercise of having the correct dependencies, using the antlr plugin etc... It compiles, but the annotation processors get in the way.

Full branch: https://github.com/fge/NBStudio/tree/topic/gradle

The difference from the original:

- rename src to src/main/java;
- all non java files into src/main/resources.

The build.gradle of submodule `NBStudioCore` reads:

```
apply(plugin: "antlr");

repositories {
    mavenCentral();
    maven {
        url "http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2";
    }
}

dependencies {
    antlr(group: "org.antlr", name: "antlr4", version: "4.5");

    compile project(":cachedb");

    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api", name: "org-openide-util",
        version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api", name: "org-netbeans-api-search",
        version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api", name: "org-netbeans-modules-lexer",
        version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api", name: "org-netbeans-modules-parsing-api",
        version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api", name: "org-netbeans-modules-editor",
        version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api",
        name: "org-netbeans-modules-editor-completion", version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api",
        name: "org-netbeans-spi-editor-hints", version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api", name: "org-netbeans-core-multiview",
        version: "RELEASE80");
    compile(group: "org.netbeans.api", name: "org-netbeans-modules-csl-api",
        version: "RELEASE80");
}
```

And the `compileJava` task output (run from within directory `NBStudioCore` with `../gradlew compileJava`) is this:

```
:NBStudioCore:clean
:NBStudioCore:generateGrammarSource
:cachedb:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:cachedb:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:cachedb:classes UP-TO-DATE
:cachedb:jar UP-TO-DATE
:NBStudioCore:compileJava
[...]
/home/fge/work/src/NBStudio/NBStudioCore/src/main/java/org/nbstudio/core/cls/clsVisualElement.java:19: error: Cannot find resource org/nbstudio/core/cls/class.png
@MultiViewElement.Registration(
^
[...]
/home/fge/work/src/NBStudio/NBStudioCore/src/main/java/org/nbstudio/core/OpenFileAction.java:30: error: Cannot find resource org/nbstudio/Bundle.properties
public class OpenFileAction implements ActionListener {
       ^
[...]
/home/fge/work/src/NBStudio/NBStudioCore/src/main/java/org/nbstudio/core/bas/package-info.java:5: error: Cannot find resource org/nbstudio/core/bas/bas.gif
@TemplateRegistration(folder = "Cache", content = "basTemplate.bas", displayName = "BAS Routine")
^
[...]
/home/fge/work/src/NBStudio/NBStudioCore/src/main/java/org/nbstudio/core/cls/newFileWizard.java:23: error: Cannot find resource org/nbstudio/core/cls/clsTemplate.cls
@TemplateRegistration(folder = "Cache", content = "clsTemplate.cls", displayName = "Cache Class")
^
[...]
warning: layer file Editors/text/isc-cls/MultiView/org-nbstudio-core-cls-clsVisualElement.instance was never written
warning: layer file Actions/System/org-netbeans-modules-openfile-OpenFileAction.instance was never written
warning: layer file Loaders/text/isc-bas/Factories/org-nbstudio-core-bas-basDataObject.instance was never written
warning: layer file Templates/Cache/clsTemplate.cls was never written
4 errors
36 warnings
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':NBStudioCore:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 7.121 secs
```

If I launch with --debug I see that the compile classpath does not include the resources directory. But here I need it.

I tried and added this line to the build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    // ....
    compile fileTree("src/main/resources");
```

but it adds each and every individual file to the compile classpath which is not what I want... I want the directory only.

I have tried to achieve that for more than half a day without any success! How do I do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768920/is-there-a-way-to-add-classpath-directories-for-dependencies-on-gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can control the classpath of a sourceset manually.  The following is based on a similar situation that I had:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        compileClasspath = configurations.compile.plus file("src/main/resources")
    }
}
```

This might work.