# Is there any way of making IntelliJ IDEA recognizing Dagger 2 generated classes in a Java project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, dagger-2

**Context**

I have started a personal project in java with `Gradle` as the build system and I want to use Dagger 2 as a DI. The main reason of doing that is to get used to that library and be able to use it easily in bigger projects.

**What have I tried**

I've managed to make the [Google sample](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple) runs on IntelliJ IDEA

**Problem**

IntelliJ IDEA keeps telling me that it cannot resolve the generated class (in this case `DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee`). It's a bit annoying not to know if the written code is correct (specially when you are learning to use Dagger 2).

All java classes are the same as the [Google sample](https://github.com/google/dagger/tree/master/examples/simple). Here is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
}
```

**Question**

Is there any way to make IntelliJ IDEA recognize `DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee` as a generated class (and so make it possible to go to its implementation by `ctrl + left click)?

Comment: You should be able to after you have compiled the app successfully once. Just put your text cursor into the `DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee` line on in this word and use `Ctrl + B`.

Comment: Indeed, the app is compiled and I managed to run it. I can see the generated class in `build/generated/src/coffee/` but IntelliJ keeps telling me that it cannot resolve `DaggerCoffeeApp_Coffee`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Finally I made it!

I had to add the `apt` and the `idea` plugin so right now my `build.gradle` file look like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.4"
    }
}

apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Adding the 'idea' plugin fixed it

Comment: thanks - i had an old net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin version which lead me here - setting it to the latest fixed it. cheers

Comment: Worked with me. Jazakallah.

Answer (score 23):

Simplest way I found:

1. Add `idea` plugin and add Dagger2 dependency like below:

   ```
   plugins {
       id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.10"
   }

   apply plugin: 'java'
   apply plugin: 'idea'

   sourceCompatibility = 1.8

   repositories {
       mavenCentral()
   }

   dependencies {
       testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

       compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
       apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
   }
   ```
2. Turn on `Annotation Processing` for IntelliJ: Go to `Settings` and search for `Annotation Processors`, check Enable annotation processing like below image:

[image]

Comment: Don't know why you're being downvoted this is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: I'm using the above (plus setting sourceDirs, testSourceDirs) but have found File > Invalidate Caches / Restart necessary sometimes too (or delete .idea and reopen project [losing settings])

Comment: Something additional I needed to do in order
for IntelliJ to recognize the class and deep link to it (so that we can go to source when we click the class name), I needed to set the corresponding generated sources directory as "generated sources" by right clicking 
`<workspace>/out/production/<project_name>/generated` directory and `Mark Directory As->Generated Sources Root`

Answer (score 8):

you must manually enable the ***annotation processing*** in IntelliJ.

From: Settings --> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Compiler --> Annotation Processors --> ***Enable annotation processing*** and ***Obtain processors from project classpath***

then rebuild the project and you will find the generated classes in the project.

Please note that I have used this solution in a (java) **android** project.

Comment: This probably helps Android projects but had no effect for server applications in our case.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using version `2017.3.3` of IntelliJ IDEA, version `0.14` of the `net.ltgt.apt` plugin and version `2.14.1` of Dagger and as well as applying the `idea` plugin in the `build.gradle` file (as in Pelocho's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445767/1071320)) I found I also had to tell IntelliJ where it can find the sources generated by Dagger, as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/source/apt/main")
        testSourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/source/apt/test")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what I had to do in order to get Idea to work with Dagger2 and gradle.

1. Turn on annotation processing as shown in the answers above.
2. Add the following to the `build.gradle` file in order for Idea to see the generated classes as sources.

   ```
   sourceDirs += file("$projectDir/out/production/classes/generated/")
   ```

Here's the full listing of my `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id "net.ltgt.apt" version "0.10"
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("$projectDir/out/production/classes/generated/")
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.16'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.16'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
```

Also, I had to add the following gradle task (to my build.gradle file) to clear out my `out` directory. When I moved some files around and Dagger2 regenerated the source files, the `out` directory wasn't being cleared out :(. I also included this task in my run configuration, so that it gets triggered before I rebuild my project.

```
task clearOutFolder(type: Delete) {
    delete 'out'
}
```

Comment: Thanks, using IntelliJ 2021.3.3 (UE) and this worked.

Comment: Would like to specify that I did a slight omdification in your module paths:

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("$projectDir/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main")
        testSourceDirs += file("$projectDir/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test")
    }
}

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution that worked for me:

File -> Project Structure -> (select your project under list of modules) -> Open 'Dependencies' tab

Then, click on green '+' sign, select 'JARs or directory' and select 'build/classes/main' folder.

Another solution would be to link folder with build class files using 'dependencies' block inside build.gradle:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/22769015/5761849

Answer (score 1):

Using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1 and Gradle 5.4.1, this seems to be enough:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.23.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.23.1'
}
```

I don't know the minimal versions for which this solution works, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I could not find out the cause for a long time.

Just launched and the result surprised me.
[image: IDE displays an error]
Intellij Idea 2018.3.6 -
`build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id "java"
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'

    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me on IntelliJ 2021.3.3 (UE)

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'idea'
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.1.2"
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("$projectDir/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main")
        testSourceDirs += file("$projectDir/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test")
    }
}

group 'com.codigomorsa'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.44'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.44'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.44'
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.9.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.9.0'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```