# Unable to resolve generated classes

Tags: java, gradle, dagger-2

I'm using Dagger 2 with Gradle and have everything setup and code generation is working properly.

My build.gradle:

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.11'
}

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        ... omitted as irrelevant to question ...

        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.2'
        compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.2'
        compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    }

}
```

My problem is that I am unable to resolve the classes and use them in my source, any solutions I've found are targeted towards Android which I am not using. How would I be able to resolve these generated classes as dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by enabled annotation processing in my IDE as well as adding [Dr. Pelocho's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5132804/dr-pelocho) answer.

- Apply this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33445767/1787084 to your build.gradle
- Add `apply plugin: 'eclipse'` in your build.gradle
- Enable annotation processing to the apt directory created by the ltgt gradle apt plugin in Eclipse by navigating to project properties -> Java compiler -> Annotation processing -> Enable project specific settings -> Enable annotation processing
- Change generated source directory to `build/generated/source/apt/main` to match the ltgt default directory
- Click "OK" or "Apply"

This added the Dagger generated classes to my build path and classpath

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some time ago. In your case I would say that you need the `apt` plugin. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444356/is-there-any-way-of-making-intellij-idea-recognizing-dagger-2-generated-classes) where I explained how I resolved it

Comment: Seems like that is an Intellij fix, I do not use IDEA. However I did try adding the eclipse gradle plugin with no avail.