# Dagger 2 does not generate component

Tags: java, intellij-idea, dagger-2

I totally exhausted with Dagger 2 in **non-Android** app (IDE is IntelliJ IDEA).

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.9"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'net.ltgt.apt'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.8'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.8'
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
}
```

**Component**

```
@Component(modules = {MyModule.class}) public interface MyComponent {}
```

**Module**

```
@Module class MyModule {}
```

**Main**

```
DaggerMyComponent component = DaggerMyComponent.builder().build();
```

Compiler says

> cannot find symbol DaggerMyComponent

Absolutely have no more ideas what could be wrong :(

By the way, if I run `gradlew clean build --refresh-dependencies`, there is no error, everything fine!

But as only I use 'Rebuild project' in IDE - error again. Possibly IDEA bug (time to go back to Eclipse)?

And yes, I have added directory with generated classes as a content root, so IDE can see `DaggerMyComponent`.

Answer (score 11):

I had post the issue to JetBrains

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-169387

and the solution is in first comment.

> If you use IntelliJ internal compiler for the project build you need
>   to enable annotation processing at **File | Settings | Build, Execution,
>   Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors**
>
> As an alternative you can delegate build/run IDE actions to gradle. 
>   You can find the option at **File | Settings | Build, Execution,
>   Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle | Runner**

In build **171.4073.35** `Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle` option is set by default.

Comment: Aha, I had already enabled annotation processing, as answers to other flavors of this question suggests it (for instance [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444356/is-there-any-way-of-making-intellij-idea-recognizing-dagger-2-generated-classes)), but the tip about the option about delegating build/run was new to me. Thanks for the effort to find out this :)

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Alexey answer is good, but intelliJ doesnt only have problems switching to annotation processors without cleaning, you need also validate if annotation processors are enabled in

*File* -> *Other Settings* -> *Default Settings* -> *Compiler* -> **Annotation Processors**

If this is enabled you may also change your compiler.xml in

**[project root]/.idea/compiler.xml** and enable annotationPorcessing to true for your profile. (Check Image below copied from another stackoverflow post)

```
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    <annotationProcessing>
      <profile default="true" name="Default" enabled="true" />
    </annotationProcessing>
  </component>
```

Make sure to *[File -> invalidate Cache and Restart]* after

Others reported that they had to use

**apply plugin: 'idea'**

in their gradle file to let intellij recognize dagger generated classes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to enabling annotation processing as shown by @spierce7, my problem was that I was running *Build Project* from IntelliJ's Build menu without having set the *Gradle -> Runner* settings to *Delegate IDE build/run actions to gradle*. I realized this after running `./gradlew build` from the terminal and seeing that the *build/generated* folder was created.

Another source of confusion for me was that the list of directories would not update in IntelliJ until I clicked into that section of the ide.

I removed `apply plugin: 'idea'` and it still works so that is unnecessary.

I'm not sure if *File -> invalidate Cache and Restart* was necessary but I did try that as @Emanuel Seibold pointed out before I noticed it started working.

Answer (score -1):

I'm version `2017.3.3` of IntelliJ IDEA, version `0.14` of the `net.ltgt.apt` plugin and version `2.14.1` of Dagger and what worked for me was adding the following to my `build.gradle` file to tell IntelliJ where it can find the sources generated by Dagger:

```
apply plugin: 'idea'
idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/source/apt/main")
        testSourceDirs += file("$buildDir/generated/source/apt/test")
    }
}
```