# IntelliJ Bazel and java_plugin can't recognize generated classes

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, bazel, dagger-2

I'm using `IntelliJ`, `Bazel`, `Kotlin` and `Dagger2` in my project. Everything comiles just fine and works fine, but there is one big problem with this combination. IntelliJ doesn't see classes generated by Dagger. I can manually go to the `_javac` directory of a library and mark it as `Generated Files Directory`. In this case IntelliJ will see generated classes. This approach is very inconvenient as there are many `_javac` directories with generated files - I can't mark all of them manually.

By digging in into dagger Bazel toolchain, it seems that it is exporting `java_plugin` which is used to generate classes. How to let IntelliJ know about classes generated by the `java_plugin`? I think this problem should be also actual for users of `AutoValue`, for example, but I didn't try it yet.

Comment: This ask looks similar with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444356/is-there-any-way-of-making-intellij-idea-recognizing-dagger-2-generated-classes), Please check.

Comment: @BondHan I've seen this question, but it is not similar as it is using gradle which is putting all the generated files in a single directory. In case of Bazel there are two problems: 
(1) Bazel regenerates `.iml` file which contains a configuration of what directories contain what (like what directories are generated classes ones), so I can't just configure it manually in IntelliJ
(2) Bazel generates separate generated classes directory for each `java_library` and `java_binary` rule.