# Gradle - add directory to classpath

Tags: java, gradle, classpath, build.gradle

My application requires that a `\config` directory be available on the classpath when it looks for configurations files under the directory. I currently have dependencies configured like so, though this is probably not the correct way to make a directory available to my application:

```
dependencies {
    ... //runtime, compile dependencies pulled from repositories
    runtime files('config')
}
```

I am using the `application` plugin to create a standalone zip for my project. If my `\config` directory has `\config\subdir`, `file1`, `file2`, then the plugin produces a `build\install` directory with the following structure:

```
| build
| --|install
| ----|bin
| ------ projectName
| ------ projectName.bat
| ----|lib
| ------ dependency1.jar
| ------ dependency2.jar
| ------|subdir
| ------ file1
| ------ file2
```

This does not work for my application because it explicitly expects a `\config` directory

However, this is the directory structure that I need:

```
| build
| --|install
| ----|bin
| ------ projectName
| ------ projectName.bat
| ----|lib
| ------ dependency1.jar
| ------ dependency2.jar
| ----|config
| ------|subdir
| ------ file1
| ------ file2
```

How can I make gradle add another directory to the build and specify it as part of the classpath for the generated startup scripts?

Comment: Where does your config folder live in the source directories? If it is in `src/main/resources` I would imagine the application plugin would package it as well

Comment: It is not in the source directories. It's in the project root folder. Should it be moved?

Comment: How are you adding it to classpath? Yes, I suggest moving it to /src/dist as I posted below.

Comment: I tried moving the config folder to `src/main/resources`, but my application does not pick it up. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may try moving the contents of `config` to `src/main/resources`. You probably don't want `src/main/resources/config/my-file` but instead `src/main/resources/my-file`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The application plugin [documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) says:

> Static files to be added to the distribution can be simply added to src/dist

I would try putting your config directory into `src/dist/lib` and continue adding it to your classpath with `runtime files('src/dist/lib/config')`

Note: working around [this defect](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2991) means that config has to go into `/lib` under `src/dist`

Comment: I tried this approach. I can now get the second directory structure that I've described in my question, but the classpath is still incorrect in the generated scripts. It is defining classpath as `set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\lib\config` when it should be `set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\config`. how can I achieve this?

Comment: If I manually configure the generated script to `set CLASSPATH=%APP_HOME%\config`, my application works correctly but this is definitely not ideal. I shouldn't have to edit the build output, right?

Comment: Sigh, looks like you're running into this: https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2991 and no, you shouldn't have to edit any scripts by hand after the build. The simplest workaround i can think of is to put your config folder in `/src/dist/lib`

Answer (score 7):

You may try this:

```
project('project-name') {
   apply plugin: 'application'
   mainClassName = "your.main.Class"

   startScripts {
       classpath += files('src/dist/lib/conf')
   }
```

More information can be found [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/classpath-in-application-plugin-is-building-always-relative-to-app-home-lib-directory/2012).

Answer (score 1):

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Class-Path' : '<directory>' )
    }
}
```

The above worked for me