# XML validation with Apache Validator Component in Camel

Tags: validation, gradle, apache-camel, xsd-validation

I am new to Camel and I am using uri:validator in order to validate an XML against a .XSD file. However, I am not sure I am actually pointing to the .xsd file correctly as I my gradle build fails with the following error:

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: mydirectory\anotherDirectory\myxsdFile-v1.0.xsd (The system cannot find the path specified)

In my common-routes.xml file, I have the following:

```
<route>
  <from uri="direct:util-xmltojson"/> 
    <log loggingLevel="INFO" message="XML Validation"/>
      <doTry>
         <to uri="validator:file:mydirectory\anotherDirectory\myxsdFile-v1.0.xsd"/>
         <doCatch> 
           <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>
         </doCatch>
       </doTry>
</route>
```

Is this the correct way to use the validator component?

Thank you for your help,

I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validator` component take in the uri the location of the xsd file used for the validation.

This can be:

- A file, with `validator:file:_path_`. This path is relative to the folder of the execution of your application
- A classpath resources (it's, in my opinion, the preferred way): `com/test/package/resource.xsd` : the schema will be looked in the jar, under `com/test/package`
- A remote resource, with `validator:http://remotehost/path` : camel will download the resource in order to validate the xml

In your example, camel is looking for the file `mydirectory\anotherDirectory\myxsdFile-v1.0.xsd` which it doesn't found. Check if this file exist, relatively to the execution folder of your application. If this resource is static, you should place it in your jar, and use the classpath lookup.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your prompt reply! the folder with the actual .xsd file is under WEB-INF as well as my camel configuration xml and routes file (although it is under mydirectory/anotherDirectory) I am using Gradle to build the project, are you suggesting to add the folder to my classpath as explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768920/is-there-a-way-to-add-classpath-directories-for-dependencies-on-gradle

Comment: if it's under WEB-INF, remove the `file:` part, and try `validator:WEB-INF/mydirectory/..`

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue. I am now getting the following error message: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateProducerException: Failed to create Producer for endpoint: Endpoint[validator://WEB-INF/mydirectory/anotherDirectory/myxsdFile-v.10.xsd]. Reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Cannot find resource: WEB-INF/mydirectory/anotherDirectory/myxsdFile-v.10.xsd in classpath for      URI: WEB-INF/mydirectory/anotherDirectory/myxsdFile-v.10.xsd    Does it mean that the folder/file needs adding to my classpath?

Comment: Theorically, you don't have to change compile-time classpath: The root of a war + WEB-INF/classes + all jar in WEB-INF/lib are automatically visible in the classpath). check in your war if this file exists (a war is just a zip, you can open it easily)

Comment: After testing it a little more, camel can't find file under WEB-INF so easily, as it can't use the ServletContext without configuration : try to move this kind of configuration out of the WEB-INF folder. copying it under `src/main/resources/a/b/c.xsd` make it work

Comment: Yeah, I have eventually noticed this. I moved the /a/b/c.xsd to resources under src/main and also modified the gradle.build by including the following jar {
    baseName = 'resources'
    from('src/main/resources') {
        include 'myDirectory/anotherDirectory/*.xsd'
    }
}  

This is to make sure that the build folder includes the .xsd file. No luck, though. I am still getting the same error and I have no idea where I am going wrong, really.

Comment: I looked into the .war and the .xsd is under WEB-INF/classes/myDirectory/anotherDirectory and the build directory has it under the resources folder, however the directory structure goes like main/myDirectory/anotherDirectory/ why do I have that extra main folder? Does that make any difference? Any idea?

Comment: In a WAR, classes and resources are copied into WEB-INF/classes. It's the default location, where classes are loaded in a servlet container. Your file is in your class path under "myDirectory/anotherDirectory", you can use then `validator:myDirectory/anotherDirectory/...`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104816/discussion-between-innuendo-and-jeremie-b).