# Adding classpath/directories for dependencies on Gradle

Tags: gradle

I am trying to undertand the concept where I can write my code in my plugin project and include the .class in the build.gradle of my main project where I want to use the plugin. I did refer few links[so link](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/add-a-directory-of-class-files-to-the-buildscript-classpath/6015) and [gradle forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768920/is-there-a-way-to-add-classpath-directories-for-dependencies-on-gradle). Now, I am writing my classpath in android project as below:

```
 classpath files('C:/Documents/groovy-gradle-plugin/build/classes/main') 
 classpath files('C:/Documents/groovy-gradle-plugin/build/resources/main') 
 classpath files('C:/Documents/groovy-gradle-plugin/build/libs/myjar.jar')
```

I expect to see the tasks present in the jar to be displayed in my gradle window but it doesnt show up. Am I missing somehing here?