# Common library without maven repo

Tags: java, gradle

I have three separate gradle projects. In these projects I have some code that is common to all of them. What is the best way to create common library.

- I do not want to install and maintain maven repo
- I know that I can create jar file and add it to all three projects but then I will need to manually add new jar after every update.

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to add different projects to the source code classpath?

Comment: I can add it to my classpath locally (example is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768920/is-there-a-way-to-add-classpath-directories-for-dependencies-on-gradle) but I my projects are in different git repositories so every team member can have it in different place.

Comment: The "best" way is the first thing you said you don't want to do. The next best alternative is the second thing you said you don't want to do. The only other thing I can think of that would work would be to have one Gradle multi-module build, but that's definitely not "best".

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I definitely do not want manually updating jar file. I think that running maven internal repository like nexus for just one jar is overkill.

Comment: Why you would not like to use gradle multi-module project, i.e. use `settings.gradle` and shared `build.gradle`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's any more than one person on your team you should have a continuous integration server which is publishing artifacts to a repository. You then have the option to

1. Develop one project and reference the other from the repository
2. Develop on two projects in parallel using a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html)

If it's just you then I guess you could do one of:

1. Publish to `mavenLocal()` and lookup from there (see [publishing to maven local](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:install))
2. Create a [composite build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/composite_builds.html) from two or more projects

I'd argue that even if a single developer, you should have a CI server that's constantly building and reporting test failures. So it's logical that this should be publishing to a repository too.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't qualify it as "best" by any stretch, but I think you could "publish" your common lib to a shared drive and then have the other Gradle builds use a [Flat Directory Repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:flat_dir_resolver) to depend on it.

Good luck.