# Using gradle to programmatically add resource folder to test compile/runtime classpath

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We have a master build script for 60+ components.  The individual components do not have `build.gradle` files.  What I'm trying to do is programmatically (in the master `build.gradle`) add a resource folder to certain projects.  This resource folder contains a file which must be in the classpath when unit tests are ran.  I'm trying to add this in the `subprojects` block like this:

```
subprojects { proj ->
...
 // this is the folder I need in the test task classpath
 def resdir = sprintf("%s\\resources", project(':Common').projectDir)
sourceSets {
  test {
     java {
       srcDir 'test'
     }
     resources {
       srcDirs = [resdir]
     }
   }
 }
}
...
   if(proj.name == "APROJECT"){
     proj.tasks['test'].getClasspath().each {
       logger.info "COMPILE CLASSPATH: {}", it
     }
   }
}
```

However, if I query the classpath of the `test` task (see above) I do not see the folder in the classpath.  Additionally, of course, the test is failing because the folder is not in the classpath.

If I put the `sourceSet` update in a `build.gradle` in the component folder, it works as expected.

Am I doing something wrong?  How can I get this folder into the classpath for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to get this to work by dynamically updating the `sourceSet`, however, I *was* able to get it to work by adding the necessary resource path to the `testCompile` dependency.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22768920/is-there-a-way-to-add-classpath-directories-for-dependencies-on-gradle) for adding a class folder to a dependency.

Update: It's still not an ideal solution since the "solution" only adds the class folder to the compile path, it doesn't treat it as a resource (e.g., copy it to the runtime class folder).

Update #2: It's actually working as expected. It turns out that different tests were referencing slightly different resource paths.  Adding all resource paths dynamically as noted above works fine!